# How to add invalid values enum in json schema

Tags: json, validation, enums, schema

If we want to add valid values for particular field in json schema, we will add like this,

```
"Car_Color" :{
   "type":"string",
    "enum" :["blue", "red"]
}
```

I want user to enter any value for this field but Orange.

I am expecting something like this,

```
"Car_Color" :{
   "type":"string",
   "Not-contain" : "orange"
}
```

Since there are many possibilities we can't do it using "enum". Is there anything opposite to enum. So that value can't be entered.

I want user to enter any value for this field but Orange.

I am expecting something like this,

```
"Car_Color" :{
   "type":"string",
   "Not-contain" : "orange"
}
```

I tried with "not" but it is not working. If any solution for this one please provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. You can use [the `not` keyword](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#name-not) to express what you want like this:

```
"Car_Color" : { 
    "type":"string", 
    "not": { "enum" :["orange", "..."] } }
}
```